# Writing nested loops with streams

Tags: functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I once wrote a replacement for functions like this:

```
 int[][] createMatrix(int height, int width) {
   int[][] matrix = new int[height][width];
   for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
         matrix[i][j] = i * width + j;
      }
   }
   return matrix;
}
```

But now, I found myself unable to do it again. How can that code be refactored to use streams in Java 8?

Comment: You can use nested `IntStream`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `IntStream`s:

```
IntStream.range(0, height)
    .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, width)
            .forEach(j -> matrix[i][j] = i * width + j));
```

You could also use [`Arrays#setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-):

```
Arrays.setAll(matrix, i -> {
    Arrays.setAll(matrix[i], j -> i * width + j);
    return matrix[i];
});
```

Or combine them:

```
IntStream.range(0, height)
    .forEach(i -> Arrays.setAll(matrix[i], j -> i * width + j));
```

Answer (score 2):

A more functional solution (without mutating an external variable):

```
int[][] matrix = 
    IntStream.range(0, height)
             .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, width)
                                     .map(j -> i*width + j)
                                     .toArray())
             .toArray(int[][]::new);
```